# Limit Speed in Ubuntu based on traffic

Tags: performance, ubuntu, bandwidth-throttling

I have come across a script i.e. Wondershaper

The script is terrific, however any way to make it smarter?

Like it runs after certain traffic has gone through?

Say 1TB is set per day, once 1TB is hit, the script turns on automatically?

I have thought about setting crn job,

At 12 am it clears the wondershaper, and in 15mins interval, it checks if the server has crossed 1TB limit for the day, and then if it is true then it runs the limiter,

but I am not sure how to set up the 2nd part, how can i setup a way that will enable the limiter to run after 1TB is crossed?

Remove Code

```
wondershaper -ca eth0
```

Limit Code

```
wondershaper -a eth0 -u 154000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a custom script for this, as it is not possible to do it within the system, i had to become creative and do a API call to the datacenter and then run cron job.

I also used [bashjson](https://github.com/sudoanand/bashjson), to run it. I have attached the script below.

```
date=$(date +%F)
url='API URL /metrics/datatraffic?from='
url1='T00:00:00Z&to='
url2='T23:59:59Z&aggregation=SUM'
final="$url$date$url1$date$url2"

wget --no-check-certificate -O output.txt \
  --method GET \
  --timeout=0 \
  --header 'X-Lsw-Auth: API AUTH' \
   $final

sed 's/[][]//g' output.txt >> test1.json // will remove '[]' from the code just to make things easier for bashjson to understand
down=$(/root/bashjson/bashjson.sh test1.json metrics DOWN_PUBLIC values value) // outputs the data to variable
up=$(/root/bashjson/bashjson.sh test1.json metrics UP_PUBLIC values value)


newdown=$(printf "%.14f" $down)
newup=$(printf "%.14f" $up)


upp=$(printf "%.0f\n" "$newup") // removes scientific notation as bash does not like it
downn=$(printf "%.0f\n" "$newdown")

if (($upp>800000000000 | bc))
then
wondershaper -a eth0 -u 100000 //main command to limit
else
echo uppworks
fi

if (($downn>500000000000 | bc))
then
wondershaper -a eth0 -d 100000
else
echo downworks
fi

rm -rf output.txt test1.json

echo $upp
echo $downn
```

You can always update it as per your preference.